# how to send hidden details when click on image in while loop

Tags: php, hidden-field

**this is my code**

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
$imgpath=$row['image_name'];
$id=$row['id'];
<input type="hidden" name="Id" value="' . $row['Id'] . '" >
```

**here when i click send ID to next page**

```
<img src="'.$imgpath.'" height="170" width="600" title="album-name" class="img-responsive" alt=" " />
}
```

**can i use form for it?**

Comment: You can use `Javascript`

Comment: What is the hidden field that you want to send? And where do you want to send it?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui sir look again i just update ..i want to send it to next page for exmple any page like text.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) will do the job. You just need to attach an event handler function for the click event to the image. We don'it need the `hidden element`, we will attach `$row['id']` to the `id` attribute of the `<img>` element, then on the click, we post it via Ajax.

Try this :

```
//First, make the id attribute of the <img> equal to $id($row['id'])
<img src="'.$imgpath.'" id="$id" height="170" width="600" title="album-name" class="img-responsive" alt=" " />
```

Then, add the event handler :

```
$('body').on('click','img',function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');// Get the id
  $.post( "target.php", {id : id}, function( data ) {//Post the id to the target page
     //Do whatever..
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<a href="pageName.php"><img src="'.$imgpath.'" height="170" id=id="requestthis" width="600" title="album-name" class="img-responsive" alt=" " /></a>
```

`<input type="hidden" id="hidden_user_id">`

and you can use JS like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { //ready function
    $('#requestthis').on('click', function(e){ //click event
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent the click from redirecting you to "submitrequest.php"

        var hidden_id = $('#hidden_user_id').val();
        var url = "submitrequest.php?hidden_id="+hidden_id;

        window.location.replace(url);
        //OR 
        //window.location.href = url;
    })
})
```

Comment: eddy sir but i want this $id as an hidden . query string visible on the top

Comment: @krish so what? I hope you aren’t thinking you would increase security in any way by trying to “hide” such IDs ... because that would be complete and utter nonsense.

Comment: @CBroe some people willing to hide their variables so we have to do what they said ..

Answer (score 0):

you can use .base64_encode this will make the id secure:

```
<a href="pageName.php?id='.base64_encode($id)'"><img src="'.$imgpath.'" height="170" width="600" title="album-name" class="img-responsive" alt=" " /></a>
```